# hitTestPoint() not testing for collisions correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm writing a game and it has enemies and bullets. When a bullet hits an enemy, I want to destroy the enemy and the bullet. I'm using the `hitTestPoint()` method to test if a bullet has hit an enemy. Here's the code in my game loop:

```
for each(var bullet:Bullet in this.bullets) {
    for each(var enemy:Enemy in this.enemies) {
        if(enemy.hitTestPoint(bullet.x, bullet.y)) {
            trace("hit");
        }
    }
    bullet.update();
}
```

`this.bullets` and `this.enemies` are both arrays containing objects for bullets and enemies. Here's those two classes:

```
package com {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Bullet extends MovieClip {

        private var stageRef:Stage;
        public var speed:Number = 10;

        public function Bullet(stage:Stage) {
            this.stageRef = stage;
        }

        public function update() {
            this.x += Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * (360 - this.rotation)) * this.speed;
            this.y += Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * (360 - this.rotation)) * this.speed;
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
package com {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip {

    public var speed:Number = 4;
    private var stageRef:Stage;

    public function Enemy(stage:Stage) {
        this.stageRef = stage;
        this.x = this.stageRef.stageWidth / 3;
        this.y = this.stageRef.stageHeight / 2;
    }

    public function update() {

    }
}
```

}

The problem is, `hitTestPoint` only returns true if both the x and y values of bullet and enemy are the same, rather than if the two movie clips overlap. This leads to bullets going right through enemies but it not registering as a hit. Perhaps I'm missing a bounding box?

Is there a way I can make `hitTestPoint` return true if the bullet hits the enemy at all rather than only if the bullet and enemy co-ordinates are the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want hitTestObject(), not hitTestPoint()

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29

Comment: That's better, thanks. Although it does still seem to be a bit buggy. Sometimes the bullet passes right through without it detecting a hit, although that might be due to the bullet skipping over the enemy when it moves.

Comment: It could be your frame rate.  If your bullet jumps over the object between frames, it will be a miss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if yours movieclips are too small the frame x will be just right to the object and the next frame it will be pass it, you may want to make a "hitbox" bigger, like doing the movieclip bigger with alpha rectangles.